# JNI class not found

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I try to implement a JNI to access a JAVA class by a C++/Qt program.

I followed this example for the generell part.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI
Just change it a little bit to fit into the Qt program.

And now I tried since days to solve this "class not found" error.
I read a lot of the other questions to this issue and play with the different path notations in options[0].optionString.
The test.class file is int the same directory like the .exe and I checked that this is the CWD of the program.

Do I have overlooked some obvious thing or could there be more problems?

Thanks a lot!

```
#include "MyXPS.h"

JavaVM *jvm;                      // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
JNIEnv *env;                      // Pointer to native interface


MyXPS::MyXPS(void)
{
}

MyXPS::~MyXPS(void)
{
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}

QString MyXPS::InitializeJNI()
{
        //================== prepare loading of Java VM ============================
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;                        // Initialization arguments
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];   // JVM invocation options
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";   // where to find java .class "-Djava.class.path=c:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Release" "-Djava.class.path=C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Release/"  (char *)
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;             // minimum Java version
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;                          // number of options
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;     // invalid options make the JVM init fail
        //=============== load and initialize Java VM and JNI interface =============
    jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);  // YES !!
    delete options;    // we then no longer need the initialisation options. 

    if (rc != JNI_OK) {
        // TO DO: error processing...
        if(rc == JNI_EVERSION)
            return "FATAL ERROR: JVM is oudated and doesn't meet requirements";
        else if(rc == JNI_ENOMEM)
            return "FATAL ERROR: not enough memory for JVM";
        else if(rc == JNI_EINVAL)
            return "FATAL ERROR: invalid ragument for launching JVM";
        else if(rc == JNI_EEXIST)
            return "FATAL ERROR: the process can only launch one JVM an not more";
        else
            return "FATAL ERROR:  could not create the JVM instance (error code " + QString::number(rc) + ")";
    }   
    return "Initialization successfull";
}

QString MyXPS::getVersion()
{
       //=============== Display JVM version =======================================
    jint ver = env->GetVersion();
    //return((ver>>16)&0x0f)+"."+(ver&0x0f);
    return QString::number(ver);
}

QString MyXPS::test(double height, double weight)
{
    jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("test");  // try to find the class
    if(cls2 == 0) 
    {
        return "class not found";
    }

    else 
    {                                  // if class found, continue
        //cout << "Class MyTest found" << endl;
        jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "demo", "(DD)Ljava/lang/String;");  // find method
        if(mid == NULL)
        {
            //cerr << "ERROR: method void mymain() not found !" << endl;
            return "ERROR: method void mymain() not found !";
        }
        else 
        {
            jobject result = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls2, mid, (jdouble)height, (jdouble)weight);                      // call method
            const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring) result, NULL);
            QString Qresult = QString::fromLocal8Bit(str);
            return Qresult;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I implement some code to get the exception and it is the NoClassDefFoundError. So it is not about the path to the .class file. Now I will check so compile and rumtime paths in Java.

Comment: Not 100% sure about your code, but why not simply use QAndroidJniObject http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html ? Here's a nice tutorial: https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-7/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the current Qt version is 4.7 and the Android relateted functions are not included. Updating the Qt version will be done sometime in the future. But this need to be done before.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly solution for you case, but you can take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-027/

This sample shows how to call classes from C code. It looks like in your case issue is related in class path. Make sure your C code knows exact location of *.class* file with *test* class